# Latest spotless and gradle fails to recognize gradle 'build' task

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, spotless

Just migraded a project to latest gradle, jdk and spotless 6.3.0.

It's a multi-module project, where a sample of te root gradle.build file is:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.3.0' apply false
}
...

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.spotless'
    spotless {
        java {
            googleJavaFormat('1.14.0')
        }
    }
}
....

build.finalizedBy task1
```

The problem is that after the upgrade, I am getting:

`> Could not get unknown property 'build' for root project 'foo1' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

With exactly the same `build.gradle` file, only with the old versions
`id "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless" version "3.27.1" apply false`
and `googleJavaFormat('1.7')`
it has no problems

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

actually, it had nothing to do with spotless...
but leaving this here just in case someone else bumps in the problem

while I can't fully explain what was happening that is working with the older version of spotless, the 'magical' fix was to include `'base'` plugin under plugins section..

```
plugins {
    id 'base' 
    id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.3.0' apply false
}
...

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.spotless'
    spotless {
        java {
            googleJavaFormat('1.14.0')
        }
    }
}
....

build.finalizedBy task1
```